# How to execute Step based on condition in Tranformation Level in Pentaho?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration, data-pipeline

I know that I can use condition executing at **Job Level** like below

[image: simpleEvaluation]

But I want to use condition executing at **Tranformation level**. For example I have a simple `Table Input` step, which have a query like "select id from tableA". Now based on the value of each id, I want the result row to be forward to different road. For example if id > 5, I want to execute step A and so on, else execute step B and so on. Something like below

[image: step]

Pls note that in the picture above, currently every row is copied to 2 roads, not based on condition like I wanted. Is there anyway, any trick to achive **condition executing on Tranform Level**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a are a couple of ways to do this, based on the complexity of the filter you want to run. The most common are:

If you have a single boolean choice (like in your example, larger or smaller then a certain limit value) it's most common to use filter rows (centralized).

[image]

If you have a multiple categorie splitting of actions, it can be done by a decentralized filter rows (just send the data to diffrent filter rows step which each check if it is complying to the categories, while having the distribution on copy).

[image]

But the better sollution is to go for a switch/case step where you first categorize the data and then send the data to the right step:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Filter rows` step to filter data based on your condition then you can separate into true and false routes.

[image: filter]